# How to access container from Service in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, routes, containers

I've created a service and want to access the container from within so I can access the routing, 
Should I inject the container or handle this in the controller which calls the service?

Answer (score 5):

It's generally agreed that a bad idea to inject the container into anything.

when you declare your service in services.yml (or services.xml) you can inject other services into it:

```
your.awesome.service:
    class: Hippies\FlowerBundle\Service\Awesome
    arguments:
        - '@router'
```

and handle that int he constructor of your service class:

```
public function __construct($router)
{
    $this->router = $router;
}
```

Comment: Agreed, always inject as little as possible.